# Cross section of open set in product topology is open

Tags: general-topology

Let $U \subset X \times Y$ be open in the product topology of $(X,\tau)$ and $(Y,\sigma)$. Let $x \in X$. Is it true that $U_x = \{(a,b) \in U | a = x\}$ open in $X \times Y$? Of course, it is trivially true if $\{x\}$ is open in $X$.

We know that $U = \bigcup_{(A, B) \in \Delta} A\times B$ for some $\Delta \subset \sigma \times \tau$, but not sure how to use this.

Comment: You can easily find a counterexample with $X=Y=\Bbb R$ equipped with its usual topology.

Comment: $U_x=\bigcup_{(A, B) \in \Delta, x\in A} B$.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker In your comment, $U_x$ is a subset of $Y$, not $X \times Y$, as needed.

Comment: You are right, I used a different notion of cross section.

Answer (score 1):

No, not in general, but $U^x:=\{y \in Y\mid (x,y) \in U\}$ *is* open in $Y$ if $U$ is open in $X \times Y$.... This set is more aptly named a section of $U$.